# Table Limit: Sweave

Tags: tables, sweave, r, xtable

I'm running into an issue. It seems that when I try to output more than 17 or 18 tables to a pdf document the remaining tables are ignored. When I split them across multiple Rnw files, there is no problem loading any of them.

It's not returning any errors, nor does the output of the first 17 or 18 tables seem to be anything other than expected.

- Windows 7 Pro
- Miketex 2.29
- RStudio (Using CompilePdf())
- R Version 2.14.1

I'm using the following packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

% PREAMBLE

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[linktoc=Section]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
```

Any ideas? Or things that I can double check?

Comment: You are probably specifying each table environment with the `[h]` option, which causes a well known problem: if TeX isn't able to place the first table, it delays it and *all* subsequent ones, running out of space after 18 tables.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks for pointing that out. Any thoughts on a work around, `xtable()` from R uses this option as the default and I see no option of changing it (other than building my own, which I'd prefer not to do).

Comment: You might want to have a look at the http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats package documentation (also at its "Alternatives" section).

Comment: I can think to `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\table}[1][]{\@float{table}[!htp]}\makeatother` that will make `\begin{table}` ignore an `[h]` optional argument and use `[!htp]` instead.

Comment: @Stephen `morefloats` wouldn't solve the problem, as all the tables would be printed at the end of the chapter anyway.

Comment: @egreg: I did not mean to say "use morefloats" (would have posted an answer if I had wanted to say that), but "Read section 3 of its documentation (and the links given in that section) for more information about floats" (therefore the *comment*). But, yes, my comment could be misunderstood, sorry. Well, your comment and this comment should rectify this.

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, every table is assigned [ht] options automatically.

Comment: Also, @Stephen adding `\clearpage` to the end of every table removed the issue entirely. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it as your solution since it was the first paragraph of the document you suggested.

Comment: OK, but posted the whole section of the manual, because getting credit for "rtfm" seems strange (while sometimes one just would need to know *which* manual to read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is related to `xtable()` using the `[ht]` specification for table placement by default.  This can be overridden, however.  Rather than

```
xtable(...)
```

in your Sweave file, you can specify

```
print(xtable(...), table.placement="!htp")
```

or any other specification.  I often use `"H"` from the `float` package

Comment: wow, that was hidden deep in `?print.xtable`

Comment: Even so, I'm still confronted with the same issue. `LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.`

Comment: using `[!htp]` or `[H]`?

Comment: using [!htp] I get the latex error.

Comment: I got it sorted. Using table.placement="!htp" worked after I found the unescaped %.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be in the fact that each `table` environment is passed the `[h]` option; if a table can be placed respecting this option (or the automatically provided `[ht]`), it and all subsequent tables will be queued and after other 17 tables LaTeX will hit the limit.

Enlarging the queue is not a suitable answer, because in that situation all tables will be printed at the end of the chapter.

The best strategy would be to modify how R produces the LaTeX code (which I don't know how); another possibility is to make LaTeX ignore the `[h]` option and provide a different set of options: for instance

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\table}[1][]{\@float{table}[!htp]}
\makeatother
```

will pass the option `[!htp]` to all `table` environments (generated by R or not).

Comment: `LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats`. Is what I get when I try to use this, is there anywhere that it should be placed?

Comment: Those three lines should go in the document preamble, before `\begin{document}`

Comment: Confirmed, still receiving the same latex error, again around the 17th or 18th table. Manually (f/r) removing `[ht]` from each `\table` also results in the same error, there's about 86 tables that I'm trying to pdflatex (survey data)

Comment: It's quite strange; have you got also `figure` environments?

Comment: I think it may be one of the packages that I'm using. When I remove all the preamble it outputs without issue (and without \clearpage)

Comment: By process of elimination it seems like it's some kind of interaction with the hyperref package. Sad face.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen A bogus document with my code and tables written as `\begin{table}[h]` gives no error. I loaded also the package you mention in the question.

Comment: `xtable()` (from R) outputs tables with [ht] set. Not sure if that makes a difference. Did your document have more than 18 tables?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I've tried with 125.

Comment: What system / version are you using?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen TeX Live 2011, but it shouldn't make a difference. However I don't have R; anyway it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm sinking output directly to a "tex" file and then running pdflatex. So there's nothing special going on from that perspective. Now its not working even if I remove all the preamble. lol sigh.

Comment: I found it. In the 85th table (fml), there was an errant % in the caption that was not escaped properly and this was causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

From the comment of the OP: "adding `\clearpage` to the end of every table removed the issue entirely". It is nice that it works, but it does not really solve the problem behind it. Therefore I cite the whole section of the [morefloats](http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats) package here as more general reference:

> 3 Alternatives (kind of)
>
> If you really want to increase the number of (possible) floats, this
> is the right package. On the other hand, if you ran into trouble of
> Too many unprocessed floats, but would also accept less floats,
> there are some other possibilities:

- The command `\clearpage` forces LaTeX to output any floating objects
  that occurred before this command (and go to the next page).
- `\cleardoublepage` does the same but ensures that the next page with
  output is one with odd page number.
- Using different float specifiers: `t` top, `b` bottom, `p` page of floats.
- Suggesting LaTeX to put the object where it was placed: `h` (= here) float specifier.
- Telling LaTeX to please put the object where it was placed: `h!` (= here!) float specifier.
- Forcing LaTeX to put the object where it was placed and shut up: The float package provides the “style option here, giving floating environments a `[H]` option which means ‘PUT IT HERE’ (as opposed to the standard `[h]` option which means ‘You may put it here if you like’)” (float package documentation v1.3d as of 2001/11/08). Changing e.g. `\begin{figure}[tbp]...` to `\begin{figure}[H]...` forces the figure to be placed HERE instead of floating away. The float package, 2001/11/08 v1.3d, is available at CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/float
- The placeins package provides the command `\FloatBarrier`. Floats occurring before the `\FloatBarrier` are not allowed to float to a later place, and floats occurring after the `\FloatBarrier` are not allowed to float to a earlier place than the `\FloatBarrier`. (There can be more than one `\FloatBarrier` in a document.) The same package also provides an option to add to section headings automatically `\FloatBarriers`. It is further possible to make `\FloatBarriers` less strict (see that package’s documentation). The placeins package, 2005/04/18 v2.2, is available at CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins

> See also the following entries in the UK List of TeX Frequently Asked Questions on the Web:

- https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats
- https://texfaq.org/FAQ-tmupfl
- https://texfaq.org/FAQ-figurehere

> and the excellent article on “How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?” by Frank Mittelbach at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020!

Comment: Mark the "and go to the next page" after the "\clearpage forces LaTeX to output any floating objects that occurred before this command". When that is OK for your document, it is OK, of course.

Comment: Agreed, it's not a perfect solution - but it's better than it not outputting at all. I've broken my tables into 17 outputs and then `\clearpage`